# Spring integration migration to Redis from RabbitMQ to share application events

Tags: spring-integration

We are migrating to Redis from RabbitMQ in our microservice applications.

Here is our service activator

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ApplicationEventChannelNames.REMOTE_CHANNEL)
public void handleApplicationEvent(@Header(value = ApplicationEventHeaders.APPLICATION_EVENT) final ApplicationEvent event,
                                   @Payload Object message) {
...
}
```

Initially we had a problem where we were losing application event in the `SimpleMessageConverter`. We solved it by implementing a `CustomRedisMessageConverter` and putting application event into the payload in the `fromMessage` method and retreiving it from payload and create a new message headers with application event in the `toMessage` method.

```
    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass) {
        if (message.getHeaders().get(ApplicationEventHeaders.APPLICATION_EVENT) != null) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put("headers", ((ApplicationEvent) message.getHeaders().get(ApplicationEventHeaders.APPLICATION_EVENT)).getName());
            map.put("payload", message.getPayload());

            GenericMessage<Map<String, Object>> msg = new GenericMessage<>(map, message.getHeaders());

            return super.fromMessage(msg, targetClass);
        }
        return super.fromMessage(message, targetClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(Object payload, MessageHeaders headers) {

        try {
            final Map<String, ?> message = new ObjectMapper().readValue((String) payload, new TypeReference<Map<String, ?>>() {});

            if (message.get("headers") != null) {
                final Map<String, Object> messageHeaders = new HashMap<>(headers);

                messageHeaders.put(ApplicationEventHeaders.APPLICATION_EVENT, new ApplicationEvent((String) message.get("headers")));

                return super.toMessage(message.get("payload"), new MessageHeaders(messageHeaders));
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
            /* Intentionally left blank */
        }

        return super.toMessage(payload, headers);
    }
```

We are wondering if there is a better approach for doing this?

Lastly, payload in the service activator come as a `LinkedHashMap` but we want it to be an object. With RabbitMQ this was handled.

Is there any way to do the same in Redis? Or do we use headers to keep track of the type of a payload and manually convert them into an object?

**UPDATE - REDIS Configuration**

```
    @Bean
    public RedisInboundChannelAdapter applicationEventInboundChannelAdapter(@Value(value = "${com.xxx.xxx.xxx.integration.spring.topic}") String topic,
                                                                            MessageChannel applicationEventRemoteChannel,
                                                                            RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {



        final RedisInboundChannelAdapter inboundChannelAdapter = new RedisInboundChannelAdapter(connectionFactory);
        inboundChannelAdapter.setTopics(topic);
        inboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(applicationEventRemoteChannel);
        inboundChannelAdapter.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());
        inboundChannelAdapter.setMessageConverter(new CustomRedisMessageConverter());

        return inboundChannelAdapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void processError(MessageHandlingException exception) {

        try {

            logger.error(
                    "Could not process {}, got exception: {}",
                    exception.getFailedMessage().getPayload(),
                    exception.getMessage());

            logger.error(
                    ExceptionUtils.readStackTrace(exception));

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {

            logger.error(
                    "Got {} during processing with message: {} ",
                    MessageHandlingException.class.getSimpleName(),
                    exception);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ApplicationEventChannelNames.LOCAL_CHANNEL)
    public RedisPublishingMessageHandler redisPublishingMessageHandler(@Value(value = "${com.xxx.xxx.xxx.integration.spring.topic}") String topic,
                                                                       RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {

        final RedisPublishingMessageHandler redisPublishingMessageHandler = new RedisPublishingMessageHandler(redisConnectionFactory);


        redisPublishingMessageHandler.setTopic(topic);
        redisPublishingMessageHandler.setSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(String.class));
        redisPublishingMessageHandler.setMessageConverter(new CusomRedisMessageConverter());
        return redisPublishingMessageHandler;
    }

    /*
     * MessageChannel
     */

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

Comment: I would say an initial idea is wrong altogether. It is impossible to replace a fully-fledged messaging broker like RabbitMQ with some emulation based on the NoSQL DB. I don't have any answers to help you, but you probably on your own trying to reimplement many messaging aspects. It might be more closer if you share some relevant code to the Redis where you try to get a message and how.

Comment: I have updated the question.. Can you tell us which component converts payload from `String` to `LinkedHashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does not support headers, so you have to embed them into a body. See `EmbeddedJsonHeadersMessageMapper` which could be supplied into that `org.springframework.integration.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter` on both side.